# Eager loading possible through DB class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a script that is passed a table name. I want to be able to load relations of relations for the records returned. For instance, I can get this by using the classname directly:

```
Item::find($id)->schedules->load('template')->toArray();
```

This gives me what I want, however, the table name passed is variable, plural and lowercase. To fix this I could just do something like:

```
$table_class = studly_case(str_singular($table));
$table_class::find($id)->schedules->load('template')->toArray();
```

However, this is a little clunky. I'd like to do it like so:

```
DB::table($table)->find($id)->schedules->load('template')->toArray();
```

But the above doesn't work and I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax for it. How would I do this using `DB::table()`?

Comment: Your "clunky" solution is acceptable enough. You can't access Eloquent relationships from the query builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `DB::table()` your are using the [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries). Eager loading is a feature of the [eloquent orm](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent). Afiak there is no way to do this via the query builder.

But imho your clunky solution is absolutly ok, I solved a similar problem the same way. If you are just worried about the code style, you could implement a simple ModelFactory that does this "ugly" job, something like this:

```
ModelFactory::create($table)->find($id)->...
```